# if statements on textfield using greater then > swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm fairly new to swift programming so please bear with me.

My textfield:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextfield!
```

My func that contains my if statement

```
func myFunction() { 
  if (textfield.text > "1") {
    label.text = textfield.text
  }
}
```

Now when I try and build this I get the error icon and this error:

```
Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'String'
```

EDIT:

```
func myFunction() {

    if (Int(Textfield.text!) ?? 0) > 0 {
        Label.text! = ((Int(Textfield.text!) ?? 0) - 120) / 4
    }

}
```

EDIT: I'm actually trying to add the two together, but it seems instead I have concatenated them

```
    func myFunction() {

    if (Int(Textfield.text!) ?? 0) > 0 {
        calculationLabel.text! = String(((Int(Textfield.text!) ?? 0) - 120) / 30)
        insulinForFood.text! = String((Int(carbsTextfield.text!) ?? 0) / 4)

        calculationLabel.text! += insulinForFood.text!
    }

}
```

Comment: `textfield.text! > "1"`

Comment: Every time I try to do an operation " + - * / " I get an error, I'm trying to do a division.  `label.text = (textfield.text - 120) / 4`  results in error  `No '/' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'String?'`

Comment: you need to get an Int from your text before attempting binary operations to it. `Int(textfield.text!) ?? 0`

Comment: I didn't put it there because when I did my build failed, so I left it off, it produces the same error with or without it.

Comment: `if  textfield.text! > "1" {` shouldn't throw any error. `if  textfield.text! > 1 {` should

Comment: `if (Int(textfield.text!) ?? 0) > 0` should work and for the label  try `label.text! = ((Int(textfield.text!) ?? 0) - 120) / 4`

Comment: "Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type '()' and 'Int'"  "1. Expected an argument list of type '(Int, Int)'"

Comment: please edit your question and paste your actual code there

Comment: `label.text = String(((Int(textfield.text!) ?? 0) - 120) / 4)` my bad the String initialization was missing

Comment: `if (Int(Textfield.text!) ?? ) > 0 {` it is missing a 0. should be `if (Int(Textfield.text!) ?? 0) > 0 {`

Comment: yea just noticed that too....there's the whole semicolon debacle again! ;)

Comment: `label.text = String(((Int(textfield.text!) ?? 0) - 120) / 4)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Not at the moment...but may a later on in this project

Comment: your error means is : `>` is binary operator (similar to `+`, `-`, `/`,etc), yet it (the compiler) doesn't know how to deal between something of type `String` and `String?` ( it does know how to deal with type Int vs Int as in 5 > 6 or how to deal with `String` vs `String`), so you either have to convert your Strings/String? to Int, or  *unwrap* the optional version and compare String vs String ( but in your case it would be meaningless ie the operator would work, but it won't be comparing the numbers of it, it would be comparing sth else). What you can't do is to compare **wrapped** optionals

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you were trying to do.

But the problem is that you can't compare the value of two Strings with these Operators:  '>', '<', '>=', '<='.

If you want to, convert your String to an Int first.

```
if (Int(textfield.text!)! > 1) {
   label.text = textfield.text
}
```

This should fix your Errors.